# HBase Stand alone mode Functions

Tags: hadoop, hbase

When i execute start-hbase.sh in **Stand alone mode**(not in Distributed or pseudo distributed mode) it won't execute starting region servers, zoo keeper ,master back up except starting master(since no HDFS file system it cannot run region servers). Will this mode effects in recovery part of the HBase. For example, crashing the VM while HBase data is still in memstore and restarting the VM and HBase.

I tried the above experiment HBase is not able to recover.what will be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

No Difference whether it is Stand alone mode or Pseudo Distributed mode, but it will takes some time writing into WAL in Stand alone mode